# Dart + Polymer + google_maps

Tags: google-maps, dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to write a polymer element in charge of draw a google maps representation.

This is the code:

```dart
@CustomTag('map-element')
class MapElement extends PolymerElement {
  ...

  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    canvasMap = $['canvas_map'];
    initMap();
    window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(enableHighAccuracy: true)
          .listen(
              (Geoposition position) {addPosition(position);},
              onError: (error) => handleError(error));
  }
  ...

  void initMap(){
    gmap = new GMap(
        canvasMap, 
          new MapOptions()
            ..zoom = 4
            ..center = new LatLng(0, 0)
            ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          );

    line = new Polyline(
        new PolylineOptions ()
          ..map = gmap
          ..strokeColor='#0022ee'
          ..geodesic=true
          ..strokeOpacity=0.7
          ..strokeWeight=2
          ..visible=true);
  }

}
```

And this is the exception thrown when I try to create an instance of GMap:

```dart
Class 'GElement' has no instance method '[]'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '[]'
Receiver: Instance of 'GElement'
Arguments: ["maps"]
```

I think the problem is because polymer uses DOM shadow, do you know any workaround?

Here is the whole project: https://github.com/carlosvin/snowroute

---

Now it is working, here you can try it: http://carlosvin.github.io/snowroute/

I have added javascript tag only in index.html, not in polymer element declaration.

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>`

My try is in https://github.com/carlosvin/snowroute , the relevant files for this question are: web/map_element.dart, web/map_element.html and web/index.html.

Comment: I don't have time now to serach, but I think there were similar questions for Angular.dart where the answer might work for you too.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to look for Angular.dart then I'll publish my researching results. I was looking for similar issues for Polymer.dart, but I could not find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you're just missing the JavaScript tag

```dart
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I also tried to do what you're doing and forgot to include this, and got the same error.  I found you can include it here

```dart
<polymer-element name="map-element">
  <template>
    <div id="canvas_map"></div>
  </template>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="application/dart" src="map_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Or you can include it in the main index.html file.

Though this doesn't implement the CSS you must apply to actually size and see the map, that's another question, one which I've already answered here [How to use javascript from Dart inside a polymer element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801694/how-to-use-javascript-from-dart-inside-a-polymer-element/28205381#28205381).

Comment: Thanks, now it is working using only javascript tag in index.hmlt, not in polymer-element. I´m going to edit the question.